# Magneto theme installation

Tags: magento, magento2

I am a newbie in magento.
I am trying to install the magenta theme in my system as provided by my client. The file my client provided is only the sources folder and i cannot see any app,js,lib,skin,.htaccess folder or file. The url of the theme i ma trying to install is https://livedemo00.template-help.com/magento_49364/ and the source folder contain db,pages,static_blocks etc.[Screenshot of source folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjhF7.png)

Thank You in advance.

Comment: For your kind information this "Screenshot of source folder" is not Theme source because in this folder contain only PSD , Product Images , Statick Block and Pages. so for theme you need to contact to your client so he/she will HELP you..!

Comment: Thank you . i requested the client for the theme bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared theme zip file is not correct. You need to ask for other files that contain Theme Package including template, layout and css files. In Theme zip file, Source folder only contain the SQL file, Product Images, Original PSD file and static block HTML content files.

Comment: Thank you . i requested the client for the theme bundle.